# How to regenerate .laz headers?

Tags: las, laspy

We have a series of .laz files that have corrupted headers, the laspy to read the laz files, the header shows max and min as [0,0,0]. We do have other files that have correct headers so we know it's the issue with the files instead of laspy.

If I use laszip in command line tool to merge any two laz files, it can automatically recalculate the offset and correct the header. I'm wondering if there's any way to use something like

```
las = laspy.read("some_file.laz")
las.header = calculate_header(las.points)
las.write("with_correct_headers.laz")
```

to force it to recalculate the offsets, max, min, etc.